# How to Intercept a css get request

Tags: php, jquery, css, apache, http

I'm building a custom Themeroller and in order to reflect the styling changes in the page I was thinking that once the client makes a styling change ,I'll add a link:

```
http://my.domain/styles.css?param=someoval
```

Then, I'll intercept the get request, modify the css and serve it.

How can i do it with apache http server and php?

Comment: You can build a css file with a php.

Comment: Start by adding css files to the files parsed by PHP in the config files or .htaccess, and then just write PHP in your CSS file. All caching of files will go out the window at the same time of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The styles.css file must be a php script, for example:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");

$param = isset($_GET['param']) ? $_GET['param'] : null;
?>

body, html {
    background-color: #FFF;
    <?php if (isset($param)) : ?>
         font-family: <?php echo $param; ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like below

Here your file css

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");

$param = $_GET['param']; // reciving params 

if($param='somethin'){

echo ".div{ some css }";

}else{

echo ".p{ some css }";

}
```

your css could be called like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.php?param=someoval" />
```